# Still getting session ID after session destruction

Tags: java, jsp, session

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
out.println(session.getId());
// processRequest(request, response);
}
```

This is servlet logout called from a jsp page.I am trying to destruct the session but after the function session.invalidate() , its still printing the session ID. Is my session has been destroyed or it will take some time for destruction after executing the invalidate function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It destroys immediately. it will not set Id to null. It just unbinds any objects bound to it

Answer (score 1):

Session is `invalidated` immediately once you call `.invalidate` method

From docs ,

```
invalidate

void invalidate()
Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.
```

To check whether it is invalidated ,  get an attribute from the session and check for its value. For ex,

```
String value= (String)session.getAttribute("value");
out.print(value);
```

it will print `null` in this case

<sub>Note: you have already set the `value` in the `session` before checking in the above case</sub>

Hope this helps!!